# Can I store the symfony 5 cache in memcached from a folder var/cache?

Tags: symfony

symfony 5 stores some cache in folders ./var/cache
There are usually many different files stored there, etc. I'm interested in whether this cache can be moved to memcached?

memcached itself is installed and ready to work, but I do not know if this is possible and if so, how to register the config?

*PS: I searched in Google for this question, but on the request of caching symfony 5 with memcached, I always got to the examples of controllers and working with memcached from them, but this is not the case at all...*

Comment: I would assume, that the default for almost all caches is to *write* to a *file path* that is a sub directory of the project dir (this is true for example for doctrine's proxy cache), usually projectdir/var/cache/... . I'm not *certain*, but I would assume you could configure a [stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) and use as the base cache path `yourstreamcontext://`. This could probably work, however, I found no library that does this. the next level would be a fuse file system wrapper for memcached. this exists, but I have no reason to trust it. so. bad luck

Comment: Symfony uses its own cache pool `cache.system` and also provides one for use by the application itself `cache.app`. When you configure these pools to use the memcached adapter it should write the cache files there.

Comment: dbrumann - Thanks for the answer, I found how to configure the `cache.yaml` for Redis I can't find how to do this for memcached - do you happen to have this cherished config line?

Comment: Docs has everything you need : [check Cache config] (https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#creating-custom-namespaced-pools)

Comment: Thanks! formalize this as an answer so that I can accept it!